# Multiple requests

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.1

I am pretty new to Magento 2 and I saw a strange thing which I do not understand. For example when I clicked on a product from a category there are two requests sent. I mean that the code from **`pub/index.php`** is executed two times.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this default in Magento 2?

Comment: Where are you seeing this? In the web inspector network tab?

Comment: I'm using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

This might be something very ordinary, I don't know. Something a bit more farfetched: One time, I had a dynamically placed CSS background (via PHP variable), but when left empty, the browser would load the entire page a second time (looking at the *Network* tab of the developers toolbar):

```
<div style="background-image: url('');"></div>
```

Might also happen with:

```
<img src="" />
```

Comment: Is there any browser extension which can help me find possible causes like this?

Comment: Google Chrome Developer Tools (built in), FireFox Developer Tools (built in), FireFox Firebug (extension), Internet Explorer/Edge Developer Tools (built in)...